# Going trough Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am learning PHP and I got stuck on this part.

I need to create Array and go trough It with For loop but I got stuck. I either get Array to String conversion error or blank page.

```
$array = array(
    array(1, "FirstName1", "LastName1", "email1@gmail.com"),
    array(2, "FirstName2", "LastName2", "email2@gmail.com"),
    array(3, "FirstName3", "LastName3", "email3@gmail.com"),        
);
```

This is how my array needs to look. In what way I can use for loop to go trough it?

Also what is good way to go trough multidimensional array with string indexes like this?

```
$array = array(    
    array("ID" => 1,"fname" => "name","lname" => "name","email" => "mail@gmail.com"), 
    array("ID" => 2,"fname" => "name","lname" => "name","email" => "mail@gmail.com"),
    array("ID" => 3,"fname" => "name","lname" => "name","email" => "mail@gmail.com")    
);
```

Comment: Welcome. Please show your loop code.

Comment: I was using this $length = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  print $array[$i];
} only way i can print it usint print_r() but I need to use for

Comment: `$array` is an array of arrays. You should probably [learn about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) from the official doc.

Answer (score 0):

So `$array` is an array of associated arrays. To print all values in it, do the following:

```
// Loop thorugh the $array
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
    echo 'Printing '.$i.' row';
    // Loop through each element of the $array
    foreach($array[$i] as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo $key." = ".$value.PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;

}
```

Comment: Why use a "for" loop when we have a foreach in php?

Comment: It is a matter of style and preference

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now I have one more question maybe stupid but is PHP_EOL must? I ussualy see br used

Comment: Depends on your context. `<br>` is a newline tag in HTML, `PHP_EOL` or "\n" is a return character in text environments. Anyway, it is for formatting purposes only